# How to pass arguments from one class into a UIView class? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` class in my app which plots a line graph. In there, I assign my `graphPoints` variables like so :

```
var graphPoints:[Int] = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
var graphPoints2:[Int] = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
```

What I want to do is pass an array of `Int` from another class and assign those variables, but I am not sure how to do it. Initially i put all my code into one `func` with `array [Int]` as parameters and called it from another class but it stopped plotting the graph altogether. How do i do this?

Here is my `UIVIew` `GraphPlotter` class code :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GraphPlotter: UIView {

var graphPoints:[Int] = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
var graphPoints2:[Int] = [1,2,3,5,7,9]

//1 - the properties for the gradient
var startColor: UIColor = UIColor.redColor()
var endColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let width = rect.width
    let height = rect.height

    //set up background clipping area
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
        byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.AllCorners,
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0))
    path.addClip()

    //2 - get the current context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let colors = [startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor]

    //3 - set up the color space
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    //4 - set up the color stops
    let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

    //5 - create the gradient
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,
        colors,
        colorLocations)

    //6 - draw the gradient
    var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var endPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.bounds.height)
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context,
        gradient,
        startPoint,
        endPoint,
        [])

    //calculate the x point

    let margin:CGFloat = 40.0
    let columnXPoint = { (column:Int) -> CGFloat in
        //Calculate gap between points
        let spacer = (width - margin*2 - 4) /
            CGFloat((self.graphPoints.count - 1))
        var x:CGFloat = CGFloat(column) * spacer
        x += margin + 2
        return x
    }

    // calculate the y point

    let topBorder:CGFloat = 60
    let bottomBorder:CGFloat = 50
    let graphHeight = height - topBorder - bottomBorder
    let maxValue = graphPoints2.maxElement()!
    let columnYPoint = { (graphPoint2:Int) -> CGFloat in
        var y:CGFloat = CGFloat(graphPoint2) /
            CGFloat(maxValue) * graphHeight
        y = graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
        return y
    }

    // draw the line graph

    UIColor.flatTealColor().setFill()
    UIColor.flatTealColor().setStroke()

    //set up the points line
    let graphPath = UIBezierPath()
    //go to start of line
    graphPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(0),
        y:columnYPoint(graphPoints2[0])))

    //add points for each item in the graphPoints array
    //at the correct (x, y) for the point
    for i in 1..<graphPoints.count {
        let nextPoint = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i),
            y:columnYPoint(graphPoints2[i]))
        graphPath.addLineToPoint(nextPoint)

    }

    //Create the clipping path for the graph gradient

    //1 - save the state of the context (commented out for now)
    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    //2 - make a copy of the path
    let clippingPath = graphPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath

    //3 - add lines to the copied path to complete the clip area
    clippingPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
        x: columnXPoint(graphPoints.count - 1),
        y:height))
    clippingPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
        x:columnXPoint(0),
        y:height))
    clippingPath.closePath()

    //4 - add the clipping path to the context
    clippingPath.addClip()

    let highestYPoint = columnYPoint(maxValue)
    startPoint = CGPoint(x:margin, y: highestYPoint)
    endPoint = CGPoint(x:margin, y:self.bounds.height)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, [])
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)

    //draw the line on top of the clipped gradient
    graphPath.lineWidth = 2.0
    graphPath.stroke()

    //Draw the circles on top of graph stroke
    for i in 0..<graphPoints.count {
        var point = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints2[i]))
        point.x -= 5.0/2
        point.y -= 5.0/2


        let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:
            CGRect(origin: point,
                size: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)))
        circle.fill()
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        //            label.text = "I'am a test label"
        self.addSubview(label)
    }



    //Draw horizontal graph lines on the top of everything
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()

    //top line
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:margin, y: topBorder))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width - margin,
        y:topBorder))

    //center line
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:margin,
        y: graphHeight/2 + topBorder))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:width - margin,
        y:graphHeight/2 + topBorder))

    //bottom line
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:margin,
        y:height - bottomBorder))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:width - margin,
        y:height - bottomBorder))
    let color = UIColor.flatTealColor()
    color.setStroke()

    linePath.lineWidth = 1.0
    linePath.stroke()

}

}
```

DBController, func dosmth where I pass the array :

```
    func dosmth(metadata: DBMetadata!) {

    let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    let localFilePath = (documentsDirectoryPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(metadata.filename)

    var newarray = [Int]()


    do{

        let data = try String(contentsOfFile: localFilePath as String,
                              encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        print(data)

        newarray = data.characters.split(){$0 == ","}.map{
            Int(String.init($0).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()))!}


        print(newarray)


    }
    catch let error { print(error) }

   //Probably wrong
    GraphPlotter().graphPoints = newarray
    GraphPlotter().graphPoints2 = newarray

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, I'd advise against separate arrays for `x` and `y` values. I'd have an array of tuples (e.g. `[(Int, Int)]`) or of `CGPoint` values (e.g., `[CGPoint]`). That way you are ensured of consistent number of x and y values.

Answer (score 0):

So your `drawRect` method is based on the two variables `graphPoints` and `graphPoints2`. Create a method whose job is to update the arrays of these two variables, and then invoke `setNeedsDisplay` - which will go on to redraw the view.

```
    func plotGraphPoints(gpArray1 : [Int], andMorePoints gpArray2: [Int] ) {

        print("Old Values", self.graphPoints)
        self.graphPoints = gpArray1
        self.graphPoints2 = gpArray2
        print("New values", self.graphPoints)

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :) I am just a little unsure how it works, I mean i copied and pasted your code and called that function from another controller but it made no difference i.e. i passed this array `[10, 2, 8, 4, 6, 9, 3]` into both arguments but it still plots these numbers `[1,2,3,5,7,9]`. Do i need to assign my `graphPoints ` variables to something else then?

Comment: You would have to debug that. When you call the methods, do you see the individual statements and the `drawRect` method getting executed?

Comment: yeah it executes the `drawrect` but with the points that I have set up by default in my `GraphPlotter` class.. And also what do you mean by individual statements?

Comment: I mean the assignments to the two instance variables `graphPoints` and `graphPoints2`.
Put breakpoints at the statements within `drawRect` where you are using `graphPoints` and see if the array contains the newly assigned values.

Comment: But that's the whole purpose of the method `plotGraphPoints`. See my edit to the answer and add the print statements to see the logs before and after assignment.

Comment: Actually it did show the old and new values...  Not sure why its not working then

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd set these up so that any update will redraw the view:

```
var graphPoints:[Int]? { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
var graphPoints2:[Int]? { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
```

Note, I made those optionals, because you generally want it to handle the absence of data with `nil` values rather than dummy values. This does assume, though, that you'll tweak your implementation to detect and handle these `nil` values, e.g., before you start drawing the lines, do a

```
guard graphPoints != nil && graphPoints2 != nil else { return }
```

But, I notice that this whole class is `IBDesignable`, in which case, you probably want a `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` that provides sample data:

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

    graphPoints = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
    graphPoints2 = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
}
```

Second, your other class needs to have a reference to this custom view.

- If this "other" class is the view controller and you added the custom view via IB, you would just add a `@IBOutlet` for the custom view to this view controller. If you added this custom view programmatically, you'd just keep a reference to it in some property after adding it to the view hierarchy. But, however you added a reference to that view, say `graphView`, you'd just set these properties:

  ```
  graphView.graphPoints = ...
  graphView.graphPoints2 = ...
  ```
- If this "other" class is something other than a view controller (and in discussion, it sounds like the class in question is a controller for processing of asynchronous DropBox API), you also need to give that class some mechanism to reference the view controller (and thus the custom view). You can accomplish this by either implementing a "completion handler pattern" or a "delegate-protocol" pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So if I understood you correctly, then I should be able to do this `GraphController().graphView.graphPoints = newarray` in another controller?

Comment: sorry, I dont want to sound dumb, but you completely lost me here.. I thought by calling `GraphPlotter()` I am calling the existing `GraphPlotter` VC? I understand your example with segue, but I guess if I just do `GraphPlotter.graphPoints` then it will create an instance of `GraphPlotter` VC and will give me an error? Also I have edited the question, I added a snippet from my `DBController` class function where I want to call my `GraphPlotter` VC from and pass the array of `Int`.

Comment: Well perhaps this shows the gaps in my code, but there is actually no relationship between the two (or perhaps very little). Basically, `DBController` is in charge of downloading a fie from a Dropbox folder which has just numbers in one line separated by a comma. After that I call the method `dosmth` which converts the text from the file to an array of `Int` and from there I want to call a `GraphPlotter` and assign the new array to `graphPoints`. Not really sure if this a proper way of doing it, but being a noob in Swift, this made sense to me.

Comment: Well my VC's are connected together by a segue, so once the table is presented with all the files in that folder, the user can click on the appropriate file, which then causes the segue to a `GraphPlotter` class where a line graph is displayed/plotted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108644/discussion-between-rob-and-user3395936).